# How to make an image can be downloaded automatically without having to open the image link with PHP

Tags: php, image

first please open this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfC6C.gif
that link is contain an image, if you open that link, the image will appear on browser

and this link is from facebook , https://www.facebook.com/588117287959322/ , it contain image too,

but if you open it , the image will not appear , but download dialog in browser will show. 
How to create like that? so user no need to right click in image to save the image, just click the link and download dialog will automatically appear on screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the MIME `Content-Type` header that the server sends. If the `Content-Type` header contains a value that the browser recognizes as a supported file type (for example `image/png` means an image file in PNG format that all browsers support), then the browser will try to display the image.

But you can also force the browser to show a "download dialog" if you want, by classifying the server response as an "attachment" - i.e. a file that is not an integral part of the document. You do that by using the `Content-Disposition` header. For example, in PHP you would say:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=" . $filename);
```

The "filename" attribute is optional and used to suggest to the browser what name the downloaded file should be saved as. This is important if the URL itself does not end in what looks like a file. For example the imgur.com URL looks like a file, so the "filename" attribute is not needed, while the facebook.com URL does not and without the "filename" attribute, the browser will have a hard time coming up with a useful file name.

Here is a full code snippet - assuming a file at /var/www/image.jpg that you want the user to download, you might write:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=image.jpg");
echo file_get_contents("/var/www/image.jpg");
```

Comment: ouch sorry , i only see the download dialog open, i dont read the description in download dialog. the description is "1.jpg which is :Firefox HTML Document (0 bytes)" , not the image file. I try to save the image with jpg type, but the image is error.

Comment: Make sure to set the `Content-Type` to the correct mine type of the image, and also - and much more importantly - send the file content itself. Check the update answer.

Comment: yes i added Content-Type after write previous comment, download dialog make a right file type. But the size is still 0 bytes, and after i read your updated answer, i dont even to write an question again, because you already answer it using "echo file", thanks again, many thanks :D

Comment: Sure, no problems. Please note that using `file()` is incorrect - check my updated answer.